# How to keep a UITableViewCell selected while I edit that cell?

Tags: ios, object, uitableview

I am making an application that keeps track of different student object's as apart of a class. Each student has a student number, name, and money balance. I have created all of the back end logic for how it work's and I have all of the student's displayed in a UITableView. I then have button's that when pressed will increment/decrement the selected student's money value. The only issue is that every time I select a student in the table view and then press the increment/decrement money button it will deselect the cell. I want that cell to remain selected so that I can just keep pressing the increment/decrement money button. I also need the cell to update each time I press the increment/decrement money button so that it will show the money on that student going up or down in the cell.

This is what one of the increment/decrement money button's code looks like:

```
- (IBAction)twentyDollarButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
        self.currentStudent.studentMoney += self.signValue * 20;
        [self updateUI];
}

- (EconoClassStudent *)currentStudent
{
    if (!_currentStudent) {
        _currentStudent = [[EconoClassStudent alloc] init];
    } else {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.testTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        NSArray *instructorClass = [self.instructorClass classAsArray];
        if (indexPath && [instructorClass count] > 0) {
            EconoClassStudent *student = instructorClass[indexPath.row];
            _currentStudent = student;
        }
    }

    return _currentStudent;
}
```

My update UI method:

```
- (void)updateUI
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.testTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSArray *indexPathsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:indexPath, nil];


    self.studentLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u. %@\n$%d",
                              self.currentStudent.studentNumber,
                              self.currentStudent.studentName,
                              self.currentStudent.studentMoney];



    [self.testTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsArray withRowAnimation:NO];
}
```

Everything does work properly, but I just want the current cell to stay selected while I am pressing the money button.

Any help would be great! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` deselects the cell when called.

Since you already have `indexPath` inside `- (void)updateUI` and aren't modifying the tableview, try programmatically selecting the row once again by calling

```
[self.testTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```

after `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed! It work's great! That was a very simple fix, too, I just overlooked it. One other question that I would have would be how to deselect a given cell just by tapping it? Essentially have it work exactly the way it does now, but if you tap a cell that is currently selected you will deselect it.

Thanks again!

Comment: It's the same strategy. Just use [self.testTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

Comment: I understand that, I guess I am more referring to where to put it. Is there a method that will be called every time a cell is selected? Because I obviously cannot put that method into UpdateUI.

Comment: Yes, there is. Check out tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:), it is a part of UITableViewDelegate. I thought you were already using it.

Comment: I am indeed using it and I actually saw that method right after I posted my comment. Thank you very much for your help! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

In XIB, for TableView you can set property "Editing" as "No Selection During Editing" or "Single Selection During Editing".

Also, you can manually call:

`[self.testTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:IndexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];`

in your updateUI.
Hope that will help.